# What is the Difference between float "1" and float "1f" in Java?

Tags: java, variables, floating-point

Is there any difference - in Java - between defining float variables like, e.g., this: `1` and this: `1f`? Is the JVM doing any casts at run-time when I write `1`, or something that could slow down my app?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java code

```
    float f1 = 1;
    float f2 = 1f;
```

compiles to following bytecode:

```
     0: fconst_1      
     1: fstore_1      
     2: fconst_1      
     3: fstore_2
```

As you can see, there's no difference at run-time.

Answer (score 6):

1 is implicitly considered as `int` literal where `1f` is considered as `float` literal

**See**

- [Floating point literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Yeah, and my second question: "Does JVM do any casts at run-time when I write 1, or something that could slow down my app?"

Comment: No, There shouldn't be anything that slowdown your performance

Answer (score 4):

Basically `1` will default to an `int`. If you write `1f` it will be considered a `float`. If you write `1.0` (no f) it will default to a `double`.

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an
>   ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can
>   optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d.

[For more info about java data types.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
float a = 1;
float b = 1f;
```

It's the same, but if you do something like:

```
int a = 1f
```

Will throw "Type mismatch: cannot convert from float to int"

```
int b = 1d or 1.0
```

Will throw "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int"

```
float c = 1d or  1.0
```

Will throw "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float"

Note that:

```
double a = 2.0;
double b = 2d;
double c = 2.0f;
if (a == b) {
    if (c == a) {
        if (c == b) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Will return 1;

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If the case like this the JVM will pass it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f = 1;
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

But it will occur exception if you do something like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f = 1.5;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - possible loss of precision
  required: float
  found:    double
    at package.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

**What we can analyze for this two example is, for the first example it automatically converted to `float`, but for the second example if you add some decimal point without the `f` or `F` suffix than it will automatically converted to `double`.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a big difference between `1` and `1f`. As you can't declare a variable without giving its type in java, Its clear `1` is an `int` and `1f` denotes `float` at compile time itself. This is nothing related to run time or slow down your app.